# Group the data in an array and get the sum from the array of object values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am new to react and javascript. Here I am trying to use the lodsh function.

I have an array of object which looks like ,

```
const data = [{
"Id": "1",
          "testone": 100,
          "test": 40,
          "Original": {
            "Id": "11"
          },
          "__Parent__": {
            "Id": "20",
            "Status": "INP"
          }
}, {
"Id": "2",
          "testone": 120,
          "test": 20,
          "Original": {
            "Id": "10"
          },
          "__Parent__": {
            "Id": "21",
            "Status": "Book"
          }
},{
"Id": "3",
          "testone": 110,
          "test": 140,
          "Original": {
            "Id": "11"
          },
          "__Parent__": {
            "Id": "20",
            "Status": "INP"
          }
}, {
"Id": "4",
          "testone": 100,
          "test": 40,
          "Original": {
            "Id": "11"
          },
          "__Parent__": {
            "Id": "20",
            "Status": "Val"
          }
}]
```

Here, I have one function which has the product Id . which I am passing from another function =>

```
cont value = (PID, data) => {
    
 
}
```

So, this function ,

I need do sum ,  where first I need to take all the object which has the same Id as PID.  The Id from object is to be `Original.ID`. If these matches then after that ,I need to check the status of that objects like , is status is either `INP or BOOK` then for summation need to take the

```
testone key value or else need to take the `test` key value.
```

So, In the given example it will be like ,

Id is 11 which is passed to a function and in the given object 3 objects where it matches.

Now,

while returning sum it will be like ,

```
100 + 100 + 40 which will be 240.
```

So, How do I do this . thanks .

Comment: You can use `data.filter(item) => item.Original.Id === PID` to get an array of items with a matching PIDS. Then you could use a `map` function on the resulting array to do the summation logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to do it with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) if you support IE9 and after.

```
const sum = data.reduce((total, item) => {
    if (item.Original.Id !== PID) return total;

    const { status, testone, test } = item;
    let addition = 0;

    if (status === "INP") addition = testone;
    else if (status === "BOOK") addition = test;
    
    return total + addition;
}, 0);
```